# Fedora: Prevening kernel upgrades until kernel-headers is available

Tags: linux, fedora, vmware, kernel

First, off, yes I do know that when the kernel is updated and the header files don't change the package doesn't need to be updated.

However, I use VMWare Worktation as a part of my daily workflow, and because of the way they check for kernel header versions it refuses to launch unless the version of the `kernel` and the `kernel-headers` packages match exactly.

Right now I have kernel `6.5.5-100.fc37.x86_64`, `kernel-headers-6.5.4-100.fc37.x86_64`, and `kernel-devel-6.5.5-100.fc37.x86_64` on f37.

In case it's helpful, The VMWare failure log says:

```
2023-10-20T22:23:02.931Z In(05) modconfig Initialized!  Lets do this thing...
2023-10-20T22:23:02.931Z In(05) modconfig Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2023-10-20T22:23:02.932Z In(05) modconfig Created new pathsHash.
2023-10-20T22:23:02.932Z In(05) modconfig Setting header path for 6.5.5-100.fc37.x86_64 to "/lib/modules/6.5.5-100.fc37.x86_64/build/include".
2023-10-20T22:23:02.932Z In(05) modconfig Validating path "/lib/modules/6.5.5-100.fc37.x86_64/build/include" for kernel release "6.5.5-100.fc37.x86_64".
2023-10-20T22:23:02.932Z In(05) modconfig Failed to find /lib/modules/6.5.5-100.fc37.x86_64/build/include/linux/version.h
```

So, it fails to work unless the `kernel` and `kernel-headers` versions match exactly.

**My question is: How do I prevent `dnf` from upgrading the `kernel` package until a `kernel-headers` with a matching version number is available?**

Currently this problem breaks my workflow and I'm stuck until a new `kernel-headers` version is released. Thanks.

Comment: The file `version.h` is reported as missing, so this does not seem to be a version mismatch. Try to supply the file from elsewhere, either by copy or a symbolic link. See the last entries in [this post](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/vmware-kernel-module-updater-can-t-compile-after-upgraded-to/td-p/898605). Also check for an update to Workstation.

Comment: Update to workstation 17.5 fixed the issue, didn't even have to recompile `vmware-host-modules`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to VMWare workstation 17.5 fixed the issue.
If you're in a similar boat, try:

1. Updating your workstation version
2. Downloading, compiling and installing [vmware-host-modules](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/tree/workstation-17.5.0) - patches for newer kernel versions for certain vmware submodules
3. If you're lucky and the same version is available, `sudo dnf install kernel-headers-$(uname -r)`
4. [Referencing this post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292049/vmware-workstation-error-modules-must-be-compiled-how-to-fix). This solution has worked for me in the past, but didn't on this occasion.